# To prevent the flag from changing when the user types in a phone number

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

problem is the user type number its automatically detect the flag i want to prevent does not

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/intl-tel-input/17.0.8/js/utils.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var phoneInput = document.querySelector('#phone');
  var phoneIti = window.intlTelInput(phoneInput, {
    separateDialCode: true,
    initialCountry: 'ca',
    utilsScript: 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/intl-tel-input/17.0.8/js/utils.js',
  });

  phoneInput.addEventListener('countrychange', function() {
    var dialInput = document.querySelector('#dailcode');
    var dialCode = phoneIti.getSelectedCountryData().iso2.toUpperCase();
    dialInput.value = dialCode;
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Please [edit] to create a [mcve]

Comment: Have you tried setting `separateDialCode` to false?